# Binding Error 4 on Listview-Style

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I wrote the following styles

```
<Style x:Key="StyleListViewItems" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateListViewItems">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Width="175" Height="175" Source="{controls:ConcatString AttachString=/JPMorganFxxR;component/Content/Icons/Items/, BindTo={Binding Path=Image}}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="24" Width="175" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                       TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use them in an listview:

```
<ListView Name="LstItems" Width="Auto" Height="500" Margin="25" SelectionMode="Single" Background="Cornsilk"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateListViewItems}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FxData.Item}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource StyleListViewItems}" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        </ListView>
```

This works pretty well, but I get some errors I don't unterstand:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
```

Why does the program dry's to bind to Alignments at the moment I use a Wrappanel as an ItemsPanelTemplate (without thisit works without errors) or why DataItem is null when it is working with the given itemsource. In examples, which can be found everywhere in the internet, its done exactly the same way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work at all? Are you having troubles displaying items in WrapPanel?

Comment: No, not at all. It works perfect. I can even blend Popups over the selected items. Works nice only that there are errors in vs when i use the WrapPanel. If I dont use the style the items are also shown but of course not wraped.

Comment: I guess it some internal error info message though it doesnt affect anything so all fine. Happy end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be fixed by setting the default content alignements

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

original [tipp](http://dotnetcrunch.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/binding-error-message-appearing-in-output-window-for-wpf-combobox/)

Comment: That worked! Thanks - a bug in the combobox-control. That would have been the last I thought of. Thanks again!